# Where did the "play on realms" option go?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

My Minecraft app now only has the option of "play" and there is no "play on realms" to be found!  I downloaded - and paid for - the multiplayer app, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get to any realms on that app either.

Answer (score 2):

To have the Play on Realms button, you must have a server or be invited to a Realms server.

If you are invited to Realms, you would have a main menu looking like this:
[image: With Realms]
If you are not invited to Realms, you would have a main menu looking like this:
[image: Without Realms]
If you want to connect to an external server, tap Play and then Edit. Tap external and then press add. Tap on the server and you should be able to connect. Using the [Minecraft for Multiplayer App](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/multiplayer-for-minecraft-pe/id609704981?mt=8) should be similar.

Answer (score -1):

You must be invited to realms to play in realms. If someone does not invite you, you will not be able to play on realms. Also the multiplayer app is not realms it is wifi networking that multiple divices can use around the globe. Once it is avalible it will be an optional paid dervice.

Answer (score -1):

The play on realms button doesn't appear when you are not creating your realm server
or not invited to the realm